# When should I use "to have a dinner" instead of "to have dinner"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

As said in [that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20492/to-have-a-dinner-vs-to-have-dinner-which-one-is-correct#comment34180_20495) commentary, *to have a dinner* isn't ungrammatical, but implies a dinner for a specific reason. Examples are:

- we're having a dinner in his honour
- we're having a birthday dinner for you

but the difference is totally unclear for me. What is changed, if I'd say *we're having dinner in his honour*, for example.

Comment: See [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/41258/12503) on another question.

Comment: @P.E.Dant my question is not about article usage.

Comment: The question of which this is a duplicate is not about article usage either. Both are about the special meaning of "dinner" with the zero article. (By the way, in your question, didn't you mean to write _"What is changed, if I'd say we're having dinner in his honour, for example."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant fixed. Also one new question is raised - what is the difference between `the dinner` and `a dinner` since both are reffered to the meal as an event. I think this question is not worthy to be asked by itself.

Comment: A native speaker infers the special meaning from context, I'm afraid. In other words, there really isn't a _rule_ at work here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant in other words, article depends on context in this case, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45070/discussion-between-jumpjet67-and-p-e-dant).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A dinner** is a different noun than **dinner**.

**A dinner** implies a special occasion/celebration/observance.  Typically this would involve a lot of people coming together for a particular purpose, at which food will be served (almost incidentally).

**Dinner** is the meal you have at the end of the day.  Although there are [regional variations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22446/lunch-vs-dinner-vs-supper-times-and-meanings) on what you call the three basic meals that you might eat in the morning, at noon and at the end of the day.

Comment: n.b., All nouns describing meals fall under this rubric, e.g. _brunch, lunch, supper, breakfast._