# Difference between 'have lunch' and 'have a lunch'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, indefinite-article

> Let's go have **a** lunch.
>
> Let's go have lunch.

Is there a difference between these two sentences in terms of what they imply?

Can "*have lunch*" and "*have **a** lunch*" be used interchangeably in any sentence? If not, can you provide some examples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use "to have a dinner" instead of "to have dinner"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/when-should-i-use-to-have-a-dinner-instead-of-to-have-dinner) Also [the dinner vs. dinner](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41244/the-dinner-vs-dinner-grammar-question) and [at/in/on -/a/the restaurant](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19689/at-in-on-a-the-restaurant).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The link says 'a dinner' is an event rather than the meal itself. If that is the case, does 'Let's go have a lunch' make a sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't usually make much sense to use the article with ***lunch***. As you can see from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%27s+have+lunch+together%2Clet%27s+have+a+lunch+together&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20have%20lunch%20together%3B%2Cc0), where ***Let's have a lunch together*** (*with* article) is too rare to even show on the chart. It's not inherently invalid though...

Comment: ...it would be perfectly natural to include the article in a context like *We should have **a working lunch** together sometime next week*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, I think it is because that lunch is a special one.

Comment: I do not think the other answers are as easy to understand and use as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let's go have lunch, John.
- Great, let's go now.

**idioms**: have lunch, have breakfast, have tea, have dinner, have supper

- I'm organizing **a lunch for Mary**, John. Will you be able to attend?
- Yes, I'd love to come to **a lunch** for Mary.
- I was planning **a cocktail party**, but your idea of a lunch is better.

**idiomatic expression of an eating [ha ha] event**: a lunch, a dinner, a tea, a supper