# Do you say lunchtime or the lunchtime, if there is a specific time you like to have lunch?

Tags: grammar

I never heard of anyone saying "the" lunch?

When is "lunchtime"?

Comment: You may want to have a look on this:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41244/the-dinner-dinner-grammar-question

Comment: @Cardinal , so I should pick "the lunch" if it's a lunch I specially prepare, say, for an infant?

Comment: I am not in the place that I answer your question, but I would say "the lunch" based on the answer under that question.

Comment: If there is  a specific time you like to have lunch, why are you asking what time lunchtime is?

Comment: @AlanCarmack, like the typical time for lunch associate with the word without article.

Answer (score 1):

One would refer simply to 'lunchtime', avoiding 'the'.

By it's definition lunchtime refers to noon (the middle of the day, 12:00), but this can vary greatly per social circle.

Examples sentences:

> *Is it lunchtime already?*
>
> *Are you coming for lunch as well*?